Can't connect to PostgreSQL in pqxx C++
when trying to connect to the database the following error appears
error text
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::broken_connection'
  what():  connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "zxctatar" does not exist

code
#include <iostream>
#include "../../include/Database.h"

Database::Database()
{
    createDatabase();
}

void Database::createDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        pqxx::connection connection_to_postgres_("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=pg_database user=admin password=15900512"); // подклбчение к postgres серверу

        if(connection_to_postgres_.is_open())
        {
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

after googling people wrote that you need to change pg_hba.conf, in the end I changed it like this (I think there might be a mistake somewhere here)
pg_hba.conf
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

I also changed listen_address in postgresql.conf
postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'

user admin created in postgresql
postgresql
                             List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------
 admin     | Superuser
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS

the server also works correctly on port 5432
ss -plnt | grep 5432
LISTEN 0      200          0.0.0.0:5432      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("postgres",pid=20277,fd=6))       
LISTEN 0      200             [::]:5432         [::]:*    users:(("postgres",pid=20277,fd=7))   

OS Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
UPD 1.0
Commands that work in the terminal
psql "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=15900521"

psql "hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=15900521"

psql -U postgres -h localhost -d postgres

in this case, no errors occur, but if I take the first command and place all the same data in pqxx::connect, an error will occur
error text
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::broken_connection'
  what():  connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

UPD 2.0
it turned out that pqxx doesn't work in a separate class, now I've moved the code with the connection to the server to main and everything works as it should, then the question is why doesn't it work in a separate class?
int main()
{
    try
    {
        pqxx::connection C("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=180305Vfcz hostaddr=127.0.0.1");

        if(C.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "nice";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

in this case everything is connected as it should
UPD FINAL
the problem is solved, all that was needed was to add a destructor to the class...


The error does not match your connection type. The error is for local connection on a socket and your connection in the code is for host connection on localhost. 2) Your pg_hba.conf has peer for the auth method which is why it trying role name zxctatar as that is what is fetching as your OS user name.


@AdrianKlaver now I get another error, terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::broken_connection' what(): connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
although in the terminal everything connects without problems


The error is still showing a  connection attempt via  a socket not via localhost as your code connection is set up for. That is the first thing you need to resolve. 2) Add the connection string you use with psql(I presume) in the terminal. Though I'm guessing it works because you have .pgpass file that contains the password. 3) FYI, pg_hba.conf the first match wins so the local and host entries at the end of the list are not doing what you think they are.


Spend some time reading pg_hba.conf it will make things clearer.

still nothing works(

That is not a useful comment. Add to your question text the latest code  or commands you ran, the configuration in use and the error message that resulted.

@AdrianKlaver the error remains the same, terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::broken_connection' what(): connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied , tried to change authentication methods, tried different passwords, tried to connect not via Unix sockets, but still nothing changes, could there be something wrong in my CMake file? I checked all versions of installed libraries and PostgreSQL and it seems like everything should work correctly with each other

Again, provide the psql connection string that does work in the terminal. Add as text update to question text, not as comment.

Check this steps:
CREATE ROLE zxctatar WITH LOGIN;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE pg_database TO zxctatar;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO zxctatar;

CREATE ROLE admin WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '15900512';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE pg_database TO admin;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO admin;

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html
pg_hba.conf:
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256

Actually this should work;
int main()
{
    try
    {
        pqxx::connection C("");
        // pqxx::connection C("dbname=somename");
        // pqxx::connection C("dbname=somename user=someuser");
        // pqxx::connection C("dbname=somename user=someuser password=somepassword");
        if(C.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "nice";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

